# Can std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0,1) return a value greater than 0.99999999999999994?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, double, double-precision

From the C++11 header , I was wondering if a `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>` object can spit out a double that's greater than 0.99999999999999994? If so, multiplying this value by 2 would equal 2.

Example:

```
std::default_random_engine engine;
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0,1);

double num = dist(engine);

if (num > 0.99999999999999994) 
    num = 0.99999999999999994;

int test1 = (int)(0.99999999999999994 * 2);
int test2 = (int)(0.99999999999999995 * 2);

std::cout << test1 << std::endl; // 1
std::cout << test2 << std::endl; // 2
```

Comment: No, `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0, 1)` cannot produce the value of `0.99999999999999995`, because `0.99999999999999995==1` ( http://rextester.com/BRWD20868 )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The maximum value `dist(engine)` in your code can return is `std::nextafter(1, 0)`. Assuming IEEE-754 binary64 format for `double`, this number is

```
0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
```

If your compiler rounds floating point literals to the nearest representable value, then this is also the value you actually get when you write `0.99999999999999994` in code (the second nearest representable value is, of course, `1`).

Answer (score 1):

`std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0, 1)` must return a value that is strictly less than `1.0`.

However, what you do with that value is subject to all the many complexities of floating point operations, including rounding errors in calculations and output.

Comment: True. But if  `x < 1`, then `2*x < 2`, because multiplying a float by 2 is exact. (Exact unless `x` is so big that `2*x` overflows, in which case you'd get infinity. But that's obviously not the case here.) As you say, that doesn't stop 2*x from being printed as `2.0` if you don't specify enough precision in the print format.

Comment: @rici: I'm just pointing out that in general floating point is more complicated than it may seem at first glance. I didn't get into specifics - mainly because there are many, and the one that bit the OP in his question is probably among the simplest to understand and avoid. Also, I have found that whenever I try to explain details of floating point, I end up getting them wrong myself.